# How to set fine-grained permissions on document library folders and documents via sharepoint 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions

I have a document approval SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow. The workflow reacts on the creation of a new folder inside a document library. The newly created folder will contain new documents uploaded by users.

I found out that I can break/set permissions on the newly created folder using REST api:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('document library')/items('id of the new folder')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

My problem is: How can I break/set permissions on the documents uploaded inside the new folder, possibly via rest api?

I really cannot find I way to do it. I need to get one level down with respect to the folder to set permissions on single documents. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use the very same REST request as you purpose? Just instead of the folder id you use the file item id

Comment: I thought there was a specific rest call for my case. Anyway, I can give it a try, thank you.